The execution order of the promise according to the return type 2
This question is similar to my previous "The execution order of the promise according to the return type", but it is a little different.
Why is the order of execution of caseA and caseB different?
The difference between the code is "return" or "return promise"
caseA: 914258367
<html>
<head>
<script>
var promise = Promise.resolve();    
    
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    console.log('1');
    var promise2 = Promise.resolve();
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('2');
    });
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('3');
    });
    console.log('4');
    return;
}); 
    
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    console.log('5');
    var promise2 = Promise.resolve();
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('6');
    });
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('7');
    });
    console.log('8');
    return;
}); 
    
console.log('9');   

</script>
</head>
</html>

caseB: 91423 -> 5,6,7,8 don't even run
<html>
<head>
<script>
var promise = Promise.resolve();    
    
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    console.log('1');
    var promise2 = Promise.resolve();
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('2');
    });
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('3');
    });
    console.log('4');
    return promise;
}); 
    
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    console.log('5');
    var promise2 = Promise.resolve();
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('6');
    });
    promise2 = promise2.then(function(rtnVal) {
        console.log('7');
    });
    console.log('8');
    return promise;
}); 
    
console.log('9');   

</script>
</head>
</html>


return promise; returns an unresolved (i.e. pending) promise

"is a little different" - how exactly is it different? And what did you learn from the previous answers that you could not apply here?

"Why is the order of execution of caseA and caseB different?" - why wouldn't it be? Why did you expect it to be the same? Why did you expect a particular execution order in caseA at all?

Why did you write return promise, what did you expect it to do? Did you mean return promise2?

In the 2nd example, promise in return promise; in the 1st then method call fulfillment handler refers to the promise returned by the 2nd then method call.
This creates a situation where the promise returned by the 2nd then method (let's call it p2) waits for the promise returned by the 1st then method (let's call it p1) to settle. In short, p1 is waiting for p2 to settle, and p2 is waiting for p1 to settle, creating a deadlock.
This prevents the 2nd then method fulfillment handler from getting invoked because promise, i.e. p1 never fulfills.
Following code is a simplified version of what your code is doing:
const p1 = Promise.resolve();

const p2 = p1.then(() => p3); // p2 will always be in pending state

const p3 = p2.then(() => console.log("done")); // fulfillment handler never called

The fulfillment of p2 in the above code example depends on the return value of the p1.then(...) method. But the value being returned is p3, and p3 is waiting for p2 to settle. This puts the code in a situation where p2 is waiting for p3 to settle, and p3 is waiting for p2 to settle, creating a deadlock.
Edit

In the 2nd example, promise in return promise; in the 1st then method call fulfillment handler refers to the promise returned by the 2nd then method call.

Why?
To understand this, let us first assume that the promise returned by Promise.resolve() is p1, the promise returned by 1st then method call is p2, and the promise returned by the 2nd then method call is p3.
Keeping the above in mind, after the following line, promise refers to p1:
var promise = Promise.resolve();

On the next line, after the 1st then method call:
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    // 1st then...
}); 

The value of the promise variable is overwritten with p2.
Then after the 2nd then method call:
promise = promise.then(function(rtnVal) {   
    // 2nd then...
}); 

The value of the promise variable is overwritten with the promise p3.
Until this point, the fulfillment handlers haven't been called yet. After the synchronous execution of your code ends, the asynchronous execution will start, resulting in the invocation of the fulfillment handler of the 1st then method call.
As this handler returns promise variable which now refers to the promise p3, you have a deadlock: the promise p2 (returned by 1st then) waiting on p3, and the promise p3 waiting on p2 to settle before the fulfillment handler of the promise p2 can be invoked.

"refers to the promise returned by the 1st then method call" - actually it refers to the one returned by the second promise = promise.then(…). Doesn't make a difference though

@Bergi corrected, thanks for pointing it out.

What about 1st example? I mean  what happens when we just say "return"? Do I get the same result as if I omitted the return statement?

@WonJinKim - return; is functionally equivalent to having no return statement in that code - a function always* ends, so it always returns something

"In the 2nd example, promise in return promise; in the 1st then method call fulfillment handler refers to the promise returned by the 2nd then method call" -> Why is that? Can you explain this a bit more? For example, if I take "simplified version of what my code is doing", p3 would be the equivalent of that, but I wonder why the promise returned in the p1.then method is p3 and not p1 or p2.

Added more explanation
